# Calculating temporal mean by hour of a large dataset

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am trying to get temporal mean by hour of a relatively large dataset. Can you please advise me how I can make this process faster?

Below is the dimension of the xr.dataset "Tair"

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (lat: 2600, lon: 2600, time: 7200)
Coordinates:
* lon           (lon) float64 -64.97 -64.92 -64.88 -64.82 -64.77 -64.72 ...
* lat           (lat) float64 -64.97 -64.92 -64.88 -64.82 -64.77 -64.72 ...
* time          (time) datetime64[ns] 1991-01-01 1991-01-01T01:00:00 ...
Data variables:
grid_mapping  (time) |S1 b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' b'' ...
SATID         (time) float64 dask.array<shape=(7200,), chunksize=(24,)>
LST_PMW       (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(7200, 2600, 2600), chunksize=(24, 2600, 2600)>
LSTERROR_PMW  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(7200, 2600, 2600), chunksize=(24, 2600, 2600)>
LST_PMW_NUMO  (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(7200, 2600, 2600), chunksize=(24, 2600, 2600)>
```

and here is what I am doing to get temporal mean by hour.

```
MEAN_LST = Tair.LST_PMW.groupby('time.hour').mean(dim='time')
MEAN_LST.to_netcdf('Mean_T_air.nc')
```

I have tried to rechunk the dataset Tair to (7200, 10, 10) and also (1, 200, 200) but none of them help. Since the mean is calculated along time, I suppose it would make sense to keep the entire time dimension as one chunk, if that is true, would a better solution be to use a (7200, 1, 1) chunk? Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you using the default (threaded) dask scheduler? Users often find that workloads that are heavy on the IO perform better with either the distributed or multiprocessing scheduler.